# How to make a list of numpy arrays all have the same shape?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a bunch of 2d Numpy arrays in a list, and I want to make sure that they all have the same shape.  I know that the second dimension is the same for each array, but the first dimension varies.

Say the shape of array X is (n,m) and the shape of array Y is (n+2,m).  I would like to add two rows of zeros to array X so that X and Y are both (n+2,m).

What is the most Python-ic way to go through the list, making sure that all arrays have the same shape?  Let's say I know what the largest value of the first dimension is for all arrays in the list - call it N - and, as I mentioned, I know that all arrays have a second dimension of m.

Thanks, everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one-line:

```
[np.r_[a, np.zeros((N - a.shape[0], m), dtype=a.dtype)] for a in your_arrays]
```

Probably more readable

```
for i,a in enumerate(your_arrays):
  rows, cols = a.shape
  if rows != N:
    your_arrays[i] = np.vstack([a, np.zeros((N - rows, cols), dtype=a.dtype)])
```

Comment: That nailed it, and the code is nice, compact, and beautiful.  Thanks, @wim!

Answer (score 2):

Relatively recently, [numpy.pad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) was introduced, so there's also:

```
>>> X = np.ones((3,2))
>>> Y = np.ones((5,2))*2
>>> N = 5
>>> nX, nY = [np.pad(m, ((0,N-m.shape[0]),(0,0)), 'constant') for m in [X, Y]]
>>> nX
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> nY
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
```