# How to pad a list of NumPy arrays in a vectorized way?

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I am trying to find a vectorized way (or at least, better than using a loop) to create a three-dimensional NumPy array from a list of 2D NumPy arrays. Right now, I have a list L that looks something like:

```
L = [ np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]), np.array([[8,9,10]]), ...]
```

Each NumPy array has the same size for the second dimension (in the above case, it is 3). But the first dimension has different sizes.

My goal is to create a 3D NumPy array M that incorporates the above data. I've been trying to use the [np.pad()](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function, since I have a maximum size for the first dimension of each of my arrays, but it looks like it would only operate on the individual elements of my list. I could then do what I wanted using the function and looping over every array. However, I'd like to do this without a loop if possible, using a vectorized approach. Are there any techniques to do this?

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827060/how-to-make-a-list-of-numpy-arrays-all-have-the-same-shape), though I'm hoping to do this over my whole list at once.

Comment: First, "vectorization", in the 'fast' `numpy` sense, means operating on a whole array with with compiled array methods.  You don't have an array, you have a list of arrays.  So iterating over the list, and padding each array to the common size is a natural way to operate.  That said, task of padding 1d arrays so they can be joined into a 2d array has come up often on SO, and there are some tricks to doing that faster the row by row padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets look at the common task of padding 1d arrays to a common size.

```
In [441]: alist = [np.ones((2,),int),np.zeros((1,),int)+2, np.zeros((3,),int)+3]
In [442]: alist
Out[442]: [array([1, 1]), array([2]), array([3, 3, 3])]
```

The obvious iterative approach:

```
In [443]: [np.hstack((arr, np.zeros((3-arr.shape[0]),int))) for arr in alist]
Out[443]: [array([1, 1, 0]), array([2, 0, 0]), array([3, 3, 3])]
In [444]: np.stack(_)
Out[444]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

A clever alternative.  It still requires an iteration to determine sizes, but the rest is whole-array "vectorization":

```
In [445]: sizes = [arr.shape[0] for arr in alist]
In [446]: sizes
Out[446]: [2, 1, 3]
```

Make the output array with the pad values:

```
In [448]: res = np.zeros((3,3),int)
```

Make a clever mask (@Divakar first proposed this)

```
In [449]: np.array(sizes)[:,None]>np.arange(3)
Out[449]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

then map the 'flattened' inputs to res:

```
In [450]: res[_]=np.hstack(alist)
In [451]: res
Out[451]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

I think this process can be extended to your 2d=>3d case.  But it will take a bit of work.  I tried doing it directly and found I was getting lost in applying the mask.  That's why I decided to first layout the 1d=>2d case.  There's enough thinking-outside-the-box that I have to work out the details fresh each time.

### 2d=>3d

```
In [457]: a2list = [np.ones((2,3),int),np.zeros((1,3),int)+2, np.zeros((3,3),int)+3]
In [458]: [np.vstack((arr, np.zeros((3-arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]),int))) for arr in a2list]
Out[458]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])]
In [459]: np.stack(_)
Out[459]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```

Now for the 'vectorized' approach:

```
In [460]: sizes = [arr.shape[0] for arr in a2list]
In [461]: sizes
Out[461]: [2, 1, 3]
In [462]: np.array(sizes)[:,None]>np.arange(3)
Out[462]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [463]: res = np.zeros((3,3,3),int)
```

and the corresponding indices from the mask:

```
In [464]: I,J=np.nonzero(Out[462])
In [465]: I
Out[465]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
In [466]: J
Out[466]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2])
In [467]: res[I,J,:] = np.vstack(a2list)
In [468]: res
Out[468]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```